# Getting an error as 'This product is already required on the parent record. while creating a Product Required Record

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice, fsl

I'm inserting a Product Required record via a flow and I'm getting an error saying "This product is already required on the parent record".

There's no validation rules existing for this error.
Is there any wat to avoid this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have checked internally on this. This behaviour is not because of your custom validations.  The Error that we are getting is expected and working as designed . I'm afraid you can only have the same product once as product required related to a Work Order. Unfortunately, This is a system validation that could not be configured from the back end

Comment: Hi  SaiPraveen, thanks for your response. Can you tell me the validation criteria please? Thanks

Comment: @PrasadRuwanpathirana, As mentioned above you can only have the same product once as product required related to a Work Order